# Does an array count as a primitive operation when it is used as an argument in a function call?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Say I have
`return A[n-1] + Sum(A, n - 2)`.
I counted the following primitive operations:

```
return A[n-2] + Sum(A, n - 2)
   1    2 3   4  5  6   7
```

I know accessing a certain index in A counts as 1 primitive operation, but I am not sure about `A` in the function call. Did I count the right number of operations?

Comment: Depends on your machine model and cost function. There is no single correct answer. (What does `Sum` do?) That said, passing a pointer to a method is arguably not even an operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Raphael, it depends on the machine model. Under the assumptions of the RAM model of computation ...

> 1. *Simple* operations (+, -, call, return, etc.) take one time step.
> 2. *Loops* and *subroutines* are not simple operations: they may involve many of them.
> 3. *Memory accesses* (e.g., indexing into an array) take one time step.

... you counted correctly operations [1-4] and 7. As for operation 5, it depends: the subroutine *call* does count as one single-step operation (according to assumption 1), but the subroutine *itself* doesn't: it is a composite operation (according to assumption 2). Finally, I would not consider passing `A` as a parameter to be an operation: `A` affects running time when it is accessed within the `Sum` subroutine, not in the subroutine call.